# 37 moderate severity vulnerabilities

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to download the ACL-vue to use it with authentication, but I get this problem ,I had this problem previously, but when I executed the command (npm audit fix) I encountered many errors and had to reuse the backup version.

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\Final-Project-t\Final-Project>npm install vue-acl --save

added 1 package, and audited 1349 packages in 51s

96 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

37 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

c:\xampp\htdocs\Final-Project-t\Final-Project>
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: This isn't an error, this is a warning saying that some of your packages have security vulnerabilities you need to address. `npm audit fix` can automatically handle some of them, but you may need to update others manually, if possible, or wait for a fix.